# Files app aka Nautilus shows lots of strange file icons and is slow

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, symbolic-link, fsck, file-server

After I ran `fsck` the Files app aka Nautilus in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS always takes approx. a minute to startup and then shows approx. 50-100 file icons/symbols in the left sidebar.

How can I get rid of them and what are they? Please see attached image. I did not find an explanation for those icons on google. When I click on them, nothing happens. Many of those "directory names" start with square brackets.

[image]

The alternative file manager Krusader, on the other hand, works fine without problems.
Ubuntu is installed on a separate, bootable and persistent USB Harddrive.

As far as I remember, all began after I deleted some files on this USB Hard drive via access from Windows 10, which was booted from the main hard drive of my computer. Thereafter, Ubuntu did not boot, so I fixed it with `fsck`. After that, everything works fine again, with the exception of Finder getting slow and showing those symbols.
I tried to remove dead symbolic links with the terminal but got an error `too many levels of symbolic links`.

Here is the output of `mount` terminal command:

```
guru@unb:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8129620k,nr_inodes=2032405,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1633356k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=8191)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18681)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_2590.snap on /snap/chromium/2590 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_2599.snap on /snap/chromium/2599 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_34.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/34 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_33.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/33 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/codium_337.snap on /snap/codium/337 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/codium_339.snap on /snap/codium/339 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_15511.snap on /snap/core/15511 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_15925.snap on /snap/core/15925 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2790.snap on /snap/core18/2790 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2785.snap on /snap/core18/2785 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1974.snap on /snap/core20/1974 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2015.snap on /snap/core20/2015 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_817.snap on /snap/core22/817 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_858.snap on /snap/core22/858 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_974.snap on /snap/cups/974 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_980.snap on /snap/cups/980 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_2987.snap on /snap/firefox/2987 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3026.snap on /snap/firefox/3026 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/freecad_517.snap on /snap/freecad/517 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/freecad_727.snap on /snap/freecad/727 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ghostscript-printer-app_783.snap on /snap/ghostscript-printer-app/783 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ghostscript-printer-app_785.snap on /snap/ghostscript-printer-app/785 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gimp_383.snap on /snap/gimp/383 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gimp_393.snap on /snap/gimp/393 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_194.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_198.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_90.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_93.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_143.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_140.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_120.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/120 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_126.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/126 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_13.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1534.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hugo_16794.snap on /snap/hugo/16794 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hugo_17056.snap on /snap/hugo/17056 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20_1.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20/1 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20_7.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20_9.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20_7.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22_7.snap on /snap/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22_9.snap on /snap/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22_11.snap on /snap/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22/11 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22_9.snap on /snap/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22_5.snap on /snap/kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/nextcloud-desktop-client_147.snap on /snap/nextcloud-desktop-client/147 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/nextcloud-desktop-client_150.snap on /snap/nextcloud-desktop-client/150 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/okular_129.snap on /snap/okular/129 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/okular_142.snap on /snap/okular/142 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/qt515-core20_27.snap on /snap/qt515-core20/27 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/qt515-core20_28.snap on /snap/qt515-core20/28 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_291.snap on /snap/skype/291 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_293.snap on /snap/skype/293 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_638.snap on /snap/snap-store/638 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap on /snap/snap-store/959 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_19457.snap on /snap/snapd/19457 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_19993.snap on /snap/snapd/19993 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/telegram-desktop_4939.snap on /snap/telegram-desktop/4939 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/telegram-desktop_4980.snap on /snap/telegram-desktop/4980 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_3078.snap on /snap/vlc/3078 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/whatsie_145.snap on /snap/whatsie/145 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/whatsie_146.snap on /snap/whatsie/146 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sdb1 on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=8191)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/xournalpp_82.snap on /snap/xournalpp/82 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1633356k,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/ghostscript-printer-app.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/cups.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1633352k,nr_inodes=408338,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/nextcloud-desktop-client.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/chromium.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/xournalpp_86.snap on /snap/xournalpp/86 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/xournalpp.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
guru@unb:~$
```

Comment: It looks like you used the error output of something as the mount point for a network share? Add the output of the `mount` command to the post please, using a [code block]

Comment: try "sudo systemctl mask snapd"

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem:
Accidentally I tried out the file manager Caja, which I must say is very nice and is, in short, the same as Nautilus, looks exactly the same, but offers 2 panes like Krusader.
In addition, Caja showed me these strange file symbols under the header named "bookmarks". So, these symbols are simply bookmarks !
Furthermore, Caja has a simple option to edit and delete those bookmarks (Nautilus does not), which I did in the Caja GUI.
So thumbs up to Caja !
I can recommend all "Nautilus aka Files" users to switch to Caja. After installing, it is possible to make Caja appear in the application list and then, add to the favourites/dock.

thanks to petep and muru, nevertheless !